# Decimal Amount Format Issue-Android

Tags: android, decimal, formatter

Declaration :

```
DecimalFormat mAmtFormat = new DecimalFormat("##,##,##,##0.00");

edtAmounts = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAmounts);
```

From xml File Edit text as

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtAmounts"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="18dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:width="170dip" />
```

From Back End  mCurtotamt is 565656565(double)

Fetching Data From Sqlite DataBase:

```
edtAmounts.setText(String.valueOf(mAmtFormat.format(mDoubleformat
                                .parse(mCurtotamt).doubleValue())))
```

but the value set into the edit text as   56,56,57,000.00

what is happening over here.

Comment: How is mDoubleformat initialized? Also, tell us how the edit text should appear.

Comment: edittext should appear as the real value like 565656565.00

Comment: NumberFormat mDoubleformat = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine for me. Maybe you are getting the wrong value from the back end.

Comment: From Back End  i am getting like this 5.65657e+08

Comment: i declared the backend as double

Answer (score 1):

When you get the value from the back end, do not get it as a String like this:

```
String mCurtotamt = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("column_name"));
```

Instead, get it as a double directly, like this:

```
double mCurtotamt = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("column_name"));
```

Then you don't need to parse it when you set the edit text, but can format it directly:

```
edtAmounts.setText(String.valueOf(mAmtFormat.format(mCurtoamt)));
```

The problem is being introduced when converting it to a String when you call cursor.getString().

Answer (score 0):

Use this one for indian format like this  "##,##,##0.00" :

```
static public String formatCurrency(Double doubleVal) {
     return new DecimalFormat("##,##,##0.00").format(doubleVal);
}
```

This function return the value in correct given format. If you pass 5555555.00 value then function return 55,55,555.00 as a string.

Comment: I have been tried your code but its not worked .ami i did any mistake but @samgak answer its worked for me .Any way thanks for your help